# AuthenticationToken not found in Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, .net, maui, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to integrate MSAL into a .NET Maui app and I'm following the following article from Microsoft:

[Add authentication to your .NET MAUI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication?pivots=vs2022-windows)

They ask you to install the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` Nuget package which I did and the next part of the article is to create a function to request the authentication token:

`public async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetAuthenticationToken()`

and this is what it is supposed to return:

```
    return new AuthenticationToken
    {
        DisplayName = result?.Account?.Username ?? "",
        ExpiresOn = result?.ExpiresOn ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
        Token = result?.AccessToken ?? "",
        UserId = result?.Account?.Username ?? ""
    };
```

I've adjusted the function and added any missing libaries but for the `AuthenticationToken`, the only option it offers is to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions`.

Surely the MSAL library should contain an `AuthenticationToken` class without the need of having to install some Nuget package from `ASP.NET Core`.

Anyone has any suggestions? Is the class called something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `AuthenticationToken` is from the [`Microsoft.Datasync.Client` nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Datasync.Client).

The docs you've linked tell you to add these `using` statements:

```cs
using Microsoft.Datasync.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

The first `using` is enough to have `AuthenticationToken` in scope.

Comment: Well spotted! I don't know how I missed that! Once I installed the `Microsoft.Datasync.Client` Nuget package, it fixed the problem! I've become too reliant on intellisense! Thanks again.